# addError in trigger is conflicting with test method written for another class

Tags: apex, trigger, adderror

**I have written a following trigger code  -**

```
trigger manageEmailCases on Case (before insert)
{
    for(Case thisCase : trigger.new) 
    {
        if(thisCase.Origin == 'Call-Center')
        {
            // system.debug('Origin is Call Center');
            // Check for invalid email account
            if(!thisCase.SuppliedEmail.contains('directlineinc'))
            {
                if(!Test.isRunningTest())
                {
                    thisCase.addError('Not saving e2c');
                    // thisCase.Support_Alert__c.addError('Not saving email2case');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I have this following EXISTING testMethod written for some ANOTHER  class -**

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false) public static void testHandleExistingCase ()
{
    // Set up the object.
    CallCenterCaseNotification testObj = new CallCenterCaseNotification();
    testObj.populateSreContactInfo(Datetime.valueOf('2013-08-20 16:35:00'));

    String description = 'account_name: testcorp customer_name: sammmmmm ' +
                     'customer_phone: +1 (707) 477-3205 ' +
                     'customer_email: something' +
                     'service_impacted: yes case_id:123 ' +
                     'case_description: testing';
    // Set up parameters for the call to method.
    Case existingCase = new Case();
    existingCase.Origin = 'Call-Center';
    existingCase.Subject = 'Test case';
    existingCase.Status = 'Closed';
    // Select an SRE to use as the OwnerId
    User testOwner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRoleId = '00E60000001GX26EAG' LIMIT 1];
    existingCase.OwnerId = testOwner.Id;// testObj.UNASSIGNED_OWNER_ID;
    existingCase.Description = description;
    insert existingCase;  // Need to insert, because methods do a Query for this
                          // case object. So cannot mock out.                   
    String customerInfoForSMS = '\ncustomer_name \n@ account_name \n' +
                                ' 123-234-1234';
    testObj.handleExistingCase(new Case[] {existingCase}, existingCase,
                               'no', 'P3 - Normal', customerInfoForSMS,
                               'someemail@test.com');
    }
}
```

**When I test the class which has this testMethod, it gives me following error, which is also not allowing me to deploy -**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, manageEmailCases: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.manageEmailCases: line 9, column 1: []

**Kindly advise what could be wrong with my trigger written above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is in the following line:

```
 if(!thisCase.SuppliedEmail.contains('directlineinc'))
```

In your test you didn't initatlized this field thus this field is null and you tried to call `contains()` on null.

You have to fill this field in your test:

```
existingCase.SuppliedEmail= 'test@test.com';
```

But more correct way for fix this trouble is checking that the `SuppliedEmail` has a value

```
if(thisCase.SuppliedEmail != null && !thisCase.SuppliedEmail.contains('directlineinc'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the issue. Now I am not getting Nullpointer exception. Do I need to write a separate test class for this trigger (as we already have test class mentioned above) ?

Comment: @SanjayWadge no problem, you do not need additional test class. if it solved your issue you can mark answer as accepted. Thx.

Comment: @Pavel....How do I mark answer as accepted ? I don't see any link or button to do the same. Sorry, I am new to Stackexchange.

Comment: @SanjayWadge http://i.imgur.com/3j1CX8f.png each answer has check mark beside the answer, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer